# Placing 3 divs(height 100%) in a container div(min height 400px)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place three divs with content in a container div with a minimum height, but it doesnt want to work. I want the right two divs to have the same height as the first and depending on the length of the content, so the colored field has the same height. The col-lg-4 classes are bootstrap. Any advice is much apreciated!

html:

```
<div class="blokken row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 blok blok1">
             <h2>title</h2><p>Long text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 blok blok2">
             <h2>Title</h2><p>Short text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 blok blok3">
             <h2>Title</h2><p>short text</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.blokken {min-height: 400px;}
.blok {padding: 40px;height: 100%}
.blok1{background: #ff9aa4;}
.blok2{background: #9aa8ff;}
.blok3{background: #b4ff9a;}
```

**EDIT FIXED IT**:

All the given solutions didnt work well with bootstraps responsive classes. Not really the way it was supposed to work but i fixed it by placing a bg with the three colors in the .blokken (container) div:

```
.blokken {
min-height: 400px;
background-image: url("../img/bg-content.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: can you put your code in a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shbptL40/5/ I edited the width because the bootstrap class doesn't come with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out a `display: inline-block` for your *.blok* class, and specify `width` or `display: block` for your parent block, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfnfgt55/)

**Update**
instead of using `display:inline-block` use `display: table-cell;` and fix the width of the blok div **eg.** `width: 33%;` and `float:none;`. take a look to the updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wkbu56ju/2/

Comment: @Erick don't forget to upvote or `+1` the answer that you've selected/liked.

Comment: Thanks! Bootstrap takes care of the width with the col-lg-4 classes. My problem is still that the height doesnt stay the same when large amounts of text are inserted at one (+400px height)

Comment: Youre awesome, this would be perfect! I still cant get it to work in combination with the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) class tho :( . I think i should have said that the col-lg-4 classes makes the colums responsive so they will slide underneith eachother on smaller screens.. Might be a little too difficult..

Comment: @Erick just updated my solution using display `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`. Take a look

Comment: Thanks for your help, It didnt work, unfortunately. I fixed it by placing a background image with the three colors behind it in .blokken, see my edit at the question

Comment: @Erick Good, I wanted to make it in pure css without a kind of image hack, this [article in Steven Bradley's Blog](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/) gives some hacks like you did.